# Is there any way to debugging Windows XP/2000 BSOD during installation?

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

please is there any way to debug BSOD errors during Windows installation in real machines even in QEMU or any other virtual machine, we have a driver that we want to compile to Windows 2000 SP4 but currently it is causing BSOD during installation from Windows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKRr1.jpg)

compile new driver for Windows 2000 , I try to debugging driver.

Comment: Sure, you already tagged the right thing: windbg. For starting, you can also just inspect the core dump (enable in system settings)

Comment: hi ,thanks for your reply , but we cannot boot to enable the system setting for dump until this driver will work because we try to boot on storport /nvme , and this is the driver that we want to create for Win2000 (driver storport)

Comment: I've never done this, but I think the serial debug console can be enabled in the boat loader. But if you run in a VM, why don't you just boot with a default IDE interface first?

Comment: We did not try it on VM, I just had an idea. Will the memory dump process load the correct information about the problem into a dump file? Will it be done correctly on the VM at the last stage?

Comment: And in the VM I can change the interface from Storport to IDE at the last stage, because if I turn off the VM the dump will not be saved to a file.

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you can enable the dump file, you can then swap back to storport and hopefully get the correct information in the dump file. You could also try running the OS from an IDE disk and only a _secondary_ disk from NVME. Only if that works switch to using the NVME disk for booting.

Comment: hi thanks ,now how to fix symbole problem ?:
Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long. Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.
Loading User Symbols
* Symbol Loading Error Summary *
Module name            Error
ntkrnlmp               The system cannot find the file specified
You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.

Comment: Assuming the crash is in your code, symbols should load automatically if they're next to the crashing file. So put the pdb next to the .sys or .drv file.

Comment: ok thanks , i succeed in this , have you any idea how to save the dump file from windbg that connected via com1 ? i try with 0: kd> .dump /k D:\DumpFile.dmp

ReadVirtual: 8906b1d0 not properly sign extended
ReadVirtual: 8906b16c not properly sign extended
Collecting pages to write to the dump. This may take a while.
Failed to write kernel dump, HRESULT 0x80004005.   windbg log >>https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1185287230818893935/1196564540205305976/success_debug_with_compatible_symbole.txt?ex=65b81691&is=65a5a191&hm=d4b3a8fa313add285a2a45a8ef7ad485f24ff27e11682bd762030381f560ce2a&

Comment: No sorry, I don't use windbg regularly.